# Configurar display_errors en OFF

Tags: php

estoy tratando de configurar Chamilo LMS en un servidor Ubuntu. El problema que tengo es que al momento de instalar desde la interfaz web me aparecen los errores que a continuación adjunto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar el display_errors esta deshabilitado. ¿A alguien le a ocurrido algo similar?¿Podrían ayudarme?. Quedo al pendiente, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

te recomendaria hacerlo mediante htaccess con solo un pequeña liinea:

```
php_value display_errors Off
```

o solo coloca este codigo en el pricipio de todas tus paginas:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "off");
```